Get model as custom shape from dia.Cell (jointjs)
I have a custom shape, which purpose is to contain the implementation details as functions, like this:
  public setBorder(enabled: true) {
    this.attr('border/strokeOpacity', enabled ? 1 : 0);
  }

When I use the element through pointerclick, all works fine:
this.paper.on('cell:pointerclick', (element: dia.CellView) => {
  if (element.model instanceof CustomElement) {
    element.model.setBorder(true);
  }
});

But if I need to use it through non-jointjs action, I don't know how to get it as correct type.
  public test() {
    const cells = this.graph.getCells();
    const changed = cells.find((cell: dia.Cell) => {
      const meta = cell.get('meta');
      return cell instanceof CustomElement && meta.id === 1;
    });
    if (changed) {
      // Property 'setBorder' does not exist on type 'Cell<Attributes, ModelSetOptions>'.
      //  change.setBorder(true);
    }
  }

changed.attr('border/strokeOpacity', 1); sets the border correctly, as does
(change as CustomElement).setBorder(true); (The latter is a bad practice as it forces the typing to be correct regardless what I have assigned to the property.)
So even though it finds the correct element based on type and is able to apply the change, the found object is not correct type. Is there a way to do this with JointJS typings?
Code example here, JointJS version is 4.0.4.
